How to retrieve main group effects from GEE in R (anova?)
I want to know if the outcome variable differs across three groups. As my data includes several family members, I use a Generalized estimating equations (GEE) model in R:
model <- geeglm(outcome ~ group, 
        family = "gaussian", 
        id = family_id, 
        data = df, 
        corstr = "exchangeable")

summary(model)

Call:
geeglm(formula = outcome ~ group, family = "gaussian", data = df, 
    id = family_id, corstr = "exchangeable")

 Coefficients:
            Estimate Std.err   Wald Pr(>|W|)    
(Intercept)    54.18    4.65 135.57   <2e-16 ***
groupgroup2    -9.11    6.39   2.03    0.154    
groupgroup3   -13.17    6.75   3.80    0.051 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation structure = exchangeable 
Estimated Scale Parameters:

            Estimate Std.err
(Intercept)      810      76
  Link = identity 

Estimated Correlation Parameters:
      Estimate Std.err
alpha    0.071  0.0684
Number of clusters:   78  Maximum cluster size: 3 

The output gives me the contrasts per group, but I want to get the main effect of group instead of the contrasts.
I tried this using ANOVA.
anova_model <- aov(model$formula, data = model$data)
summary(anova_model)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
group        2   2860    1430    1.71   0.19
Residuals   97  81033     835   

This works and gives me the main effect of group, but I am not sure if this is the correct method to do so? If not, how can I get the main effect of group from a GEE?
Data:
set.seed(42) 

df <- data.frame(
  row_id = 1:100,
  family_id = sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE), # Some participants are part of the same family
  group = sample(c("group1", "group2", "group3"), 100, replace = TRUE), # Group variable 
  outcome =  round(runif(100, 0, 100), 2) # Numerical outcome variable
)
```


The anova method in geepack provides a way to test main effects in a GEE model.
The documentation in the package for this function is lacking, but if you provide it with a GEE model fit object it sequentially adds terms, and compares the models using a Wald test statistic. See the geepack JSS article for (a little) more info.
For your data with only one variable included, the output looks like this:
> anova(model)
Analysis of 'Wald statistic' Table
Model: gaussian, link: identity
Response: outcome
Terms added sequentially (first to last)

      Df   X2 P(>|Chi|)
group  2 4.04      0.13

This result essentially compares your model to one with only an intercept. Note that you could also fit two models and compare them using this same method, e.g. anova(model.1, model.2). This might be useful if you want a test where more than one variable is added to the model at a time.

Is the use of aov() substantially different to anova? With anova I'm not getting the sum of squared or df of residuals, which I need

They are different modelling approaches. An aov() internally runs OLS (as in lm()) that don't adjust for the correlation structure you specify in the GEE. Why do you need the sum of squares and df of residuals?

I have several imputed datasets and need to pool the results of the GEE. With the sum of squares and df of residuals I can calculate the mean sum of squares of main effect and residuals, and using those the pooled f-statistic and p-value.

You probably won’t be able to take this approach using a GEE - see a more comprehensive answer from Thomas Lumley here. If you must use a GEE model and want to aggregate main effects results across imputed datasets, I’d recommend searching for similar questions or opening a new one, as this is quite a different query to the one posed originally :)
